# Image in table cell has wrong dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am handling html css code like this so that my table has a cell with images

```css
    .illustration_tr {
      top: opx;
      left: 0px;
      width: 512px;
      height: 288px;
     
      background: #eaeaea 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      border-radius: 4px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .illustration_td {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: clip;
    }
```

```html
    <tr class="illustration_tr" id="illustration_tr">
                      <td>
                        <img class="illustration_td" id="illustration_td" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/18/02/24/architecture-7139263_1280.jpg" />
                      </td>
    </td>
```

The final image comes likes this . If you see it shows 512 x 341 in chrome debugger which is not what i want . How can i make it explicit to my specs of 512 x 288
[image: ml]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to set directly the `td` size instead of `tr` size.

```css
.illustration_tr {
  top: opx;
  left: 0px;
  background: #eaeaea 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.illustration_td {
  width: 512px;
  height: 288px;
  overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<tr class="illustration_tr" id="illustration_tr">
  <td>
    <img class="illustration_td" id="illustration_td" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/18/02/24/architecture-7139263_1280.jpg" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There is still a line of white space in that container . It seems it fixes the internal; container . So i replicated it to outer container too but the white line still remains . You can see that in the above illustration too

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

`max-width: 512px; !important`

and

`width: 512px;`

this way  that image cant get bigger than 512px.

But if it does, it means that somewhere in your code there is something which is making the picture bigger (some non-constant size is most likely to be it).

Comment: already did . No impact

Comment: can you post all the parenting elements and their css? perhaps i'll be able to see something more

Comment: syeds answer to move it from tr to td works but it still does not removes the white line .

Comment: nice for syeds to help. Now, try to use web dev tools to check what that white line is. It may be margin or some padding or simmilar, so try adding margin: 0 auto; just to be sure there are no margins

Comment: @MAG I have updated my answer. Look into the update and code snippet. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.illustration_table {
  border-spacing:0;
}

.illustration_td {
      width: 512px;
      height: 288px;
      background: #eaeaea 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      border-radius: 4px;
      opacity: 1;
      background: red;
      display: flex;
      padding: 0;
    }
     .illustration_td img {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: clip;
     }
```

```html
<table class="illustration_table" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="illustration_tr" id="illustration_tr">
                      <td class="illustration_td" id="illustration_td">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/18/02/24/architecture-7139263_1280.jpg" />
                      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

Changing the display property of `td` from `display: table-cell` to `display: flex` removed the whitespace

Answer (score -1):

You can go into paint and update the size of the image, ig.